# async/await is not working with react.js inside ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, promise

I'm trying to fetch data using axios.
This code is working:

```
componentDidMount(){
    const posts = axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    console.log(posts);
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
async componentDidMount(){
    const data = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    console.log(data)
}
```

Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: The first snippet shouldn't print the actual data though. Could you try wrapping the second code in a `try catch` to see, if an error is thrown and the `console.log` isn't hit because of it.

Comment: read more about Promises, async/await, trust me you will hit many walls without exactly knowing how they work

Comment: Are you capitalizing `componentDidMount` in your code? That is not likely to work at all, method names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothig special in `componentDidMount` that could prevent it from being async. This particular issue looks like an Axios issue. It's pretty easy to check using `fetch`:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    console.log(await data.json())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you are referring to when saying "this code works":
The output in the console will not be your lists of posts, right?

But you don't need to use `async`/`await`, they are just syntactic sugar.
The value synchronously returned by the call to `axios.get` is a `Promise` so you can also use `then` and `catch`:

```
componentDidMount(){
  axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

This way you you don't need `async`/`await` support in react which seems to be non trivial to set up correctly as this article states: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/
be aware that the component will `render` anyway since it not aware that you are still waiting for the data to load. So when the data loads and you updated your state it will need to render again.

Answer (score 0):

Your both the snippets are working fine.

Your code,

```
componentDidMount(){
  const posts = axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  console.log(posts);
}
```

Here `console.log(posts)` will return only `Promise` and not actual data.

And using `async`/`await`,

```
async componentDidMount(){
    const posts = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    console.log(posts);
    console.log(posts.data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(posts.data))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(posts.data[0]));
}
```

Here also,

`console.log(posts)` - Will return `Promise` object and not actual data

`console.log(posts.data)` - This will return actual data array

`console.log(JSON.stringify(posts.data))` - This will return `stringified` version of actual data

`console.log(JSON.stringify(posts.data[0]))` - This will return `stringified` version of first record in actual data.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zaqwp1)